# How to unit test a method in an enum that might change

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, mocking, powermock

So I have an autogenerated enum where each enum contains several fields and I wish to test some of the logic of the methods contained in the enum. Examples could be "find all enums with this value in this field". However the enum can possibly change, more specifically, the values and the number of enum elements, but not the number of fields in each enum. This also includes the possibility of mocking the values() method.

Now I'm afraid if I make tests using specific values, those tests might fail if the values are no longer present in the enum.

So my options are either: Add elements to the existing enum that I might then use in the test or mock the entire enum with new values I can use in the test.

Now my question, what is good practice? I've read about powermock, however it seems to be differing oppinions on this. Any better solutions? Am I looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The part that can be easily answered: you don't need a mocking framework here.

You have enums of some content - and when you want to **test** their internals, a mocking framework is of no use. There is no point in `mocking` the `values()` when your goal is to test certain properties of these generated enums.

In other words: your test cases should boil down into code that fetches values and then somehow `asserts()` something on them. Worst case, you might have to use *reflection*, as in:

- somehow collect the names of all enum classes to test (could be achieved by scanning class path content for example)
- for each such enum - maybe use reflection to acquire certain fields - to then assert against expected results.

But most likely, the real answer is completely different: it is be wrong to unit test *generated* code in the first place. Rather have unit tests to *verify* the **code generator** instead.

You see - when your unit tests find a problem in the generated enum? What will you do ... probably change your **generator**.

Comment: I'm trying to test the methods within the enum, rather than the values themselves.